# how to force all the site logos to reference to the root url

Tags: development, master-page, site-collection, page-layout, custom-masterpage

I have a web application which contains 2 site collections and the site collections have subsites.

Currently the first site collection is deployed under the root:

```
http://servername
```

While the other site collection and its subsites have the following urls:

```
http://servername/SC2

https//servername/sc2/subsiteA
```

Currently all the site collections and subsites will have the same logo picture, but if you click on the logo it will redirect to the current site collection or the current sub site.

Can I force the logo to always redirect to the root site collection?
I know I can modify the master page for each site collection and subsite, but I'm asking if there is a more general approach that can affect all the current logos at once?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe of any out of the box methods.

I would create a solution package with the custom masterpage, you will need to hook into the FeatureActivated method to apply the masterpage to the site collection and sites below.

You may also want to create a **Staple** feature which activates itself on all new site collections or sites

Answer (score -1):

You can elegantly do it by injecting jQuery code in any javascript file included in Layouts folder:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(changeTitle, "sp.js");
});

function changeTitle(){
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;

    $("a.ms-siteicon-a").attr("href", url);
    $("a.ms-siteicon-a").attr("onclick", "");
}
```

Comment: i tried adding a script inside my style library as you mentioned, then i reference the script inside my master page after the " <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />" code but this will not chnage the redirect url for the logo ..

Comment: Does javascript code fire at all?